# Groovy TemplateEngines and OutOfMemory. Possible memory leak?

Tags: java, groovy

I am having some trouble in using the Groovy TemplateEngines in Java without running in OOM. When creating a lot of different templates it seems to me that there a lot of scripts created on the heap - which are then never garbage 
collected.

I use java 8. When running this code with -Xmx32M there are about 3000 iterations possible. After that is a OOM-Error thrown.

Here is my code:

```
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine;
import groovy.text.Template;
import groovy.text.TemplateEngine;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String groovy = "XX-${i}";

        for (int i = 0; i < (1000000000); i++) {
            TemplateEngine e = new SimpleTemplateEngine();

            Template t = e.createTemplate(groovy);

            Map<String, Object> binding = new HashMap<>();
            binding.put("i", i);

            String res = t.make(binding).toString();

            if (i % 100 == 0) {
                System.out.println("->" + res);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried different variations and ClassLoaded - but in essence the results are always the same. As I can't find any current issues with that I guess I am missing something.

Could anyone help to enlighten me?

Tino

Comment: For fun, try running `System.gc()`. I've seen odd behavior with thread-local creation running out of memory and strangely that forced the GC.

Comment: I just have tried that - and as I suspected it doesn't change the behaviour. In fact I am using the TemplateEngine in a long running application so the GC is running often.

Comment: Trying it now, at >10,000 iterations with no errors. Do you have any other arguments set other than `-Xmx32M`? Also what version of groovy templates are you on?

Comment: Oh, 32,000 caused it, I'll take a look at the heap. A `GC overhead limit reached` is a very specific type of OOM which means some resources just not getting de-referenced.

Comment: I am using Groovy 2.4.6. The rather small heap of 32M I have only added to get a reasonably fast error, so one does not have to wait hours for the error to occur. I am using Oracle JDK 1.8_91 - if that is any concern. But I also assume that I should "close" something.

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you need more than 10000 different templates? Just to make sure, you intentionally create a new template inside the loop instead of reusing it?

Comment: Actually this is just a test case. We are using the TemplateEngine of Groovy in a long running web-application and the templates are quite dynamic. So reusing the templates is not solving that issue - it is only postponing it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your problem https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8037342.

Each time the parser runs it creates a new unique class based off the number of parse being done. For instance, after a while the class names look like

> groovy.runtime.metaclass.SimpleTemplateScript4237MetaClass
>   groovy.runtime.metaclass.SimpleTemplateScript4238MetaClass

After a while the ClassLoader's `parallelLockMap` will fill the heap and nothing is eligible to be GC'd. It's sort of like a `OOM PermGen` error.

Comment: Yeah - I've seen these classes in a heap dump.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions or hints how to remedy that situation?

Comment: The only solution as I see it is to create your own instance of a `ClassLoader` and allow it to be GC'd after it runs the template.

Comment: I already tried that using an instance of GroovyClassLoader - but that did not change the behaviour at all. And as I looked in the source code of the Template-Classes in Groovy I think they are trying to do exaclty that.Anyway thanks for your effort.

Comment: Sorry to say it, but you're out of luck. You'll need to fork a implementation yourself and change https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/01309f9d4be34ddf93c4a9943b5a97843bff6181/src/main/groovy/lang/MetaClassRegistry.java#L149 to use the classloader you want.

Comment: I literally went through the code and attempted to do any overriding but even with javassit proxying it's impossible (as far as I can tell). Quite frustrating, I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache Commons Text. Fast and Efficient alternative to SimpleTemplateEngine.

```
String templateString, Map binding;
StrSubstitutor sb = new StrSubstitutor(binding);
String value = sb.replace(templateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have struggling with that problem has been a while and now I come up with that workaround.

Just call clear after run your script.

https://gist.github.com/jpozorio/38f26120e6346dfd74cecd7a147028aa